# Why my sphere render is coming out with squares and in the viewport looks fine?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I followed a tutorial and in the viewport my scene looks fine but when I render it it turns out like this:

[image: render]

and this is in the viewport

[image: viewport]

Using Eeves to render

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Instead of increasing the subdivision surface levels, you should use shade smooth on the object (right click > shade smooth). Also make sure the subdivision surface modifier's levels are the same in viewport and render

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks! This worked, The levels in the viewport were different than in the render.

Comment: so now I noticed that the sphere has a weird ballon-like texture on the sides https://ibb.co/dm3cD4s how can I smooth that out?